# PagerSlidingTabStrip with Icon And Text

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I was able to successfully implement PagerSlidingTabStrip with my app.
But my application requires a tab with Text And Icons. 
Unfortunately, I am not able to do that.

```
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.IconTabProvider {
    private int tabIcons[] = {R.drawable.ic_explore, R.drawable.ic_nearby, R.drawable.ic_road_rescue};
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    public Pager(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Explore();
            case 1:
                return new Nearby();
            case 2:
                return new RoadRescue();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabIcons.length;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
      return tabIcons[position];
    }
}
```

What seems to be wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: what is the problem you are facing. add more details.

Comment: Only the icon is showing not the title